# Error utils/math.go:128:1: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body

Tags: go

I have a problem updating some data which is as follows:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

const (
    DEF     = 20000  // or SDEF
    MIN_ATK = 100000 // or MIN SKILL ATK
    MAX_ATK = 120000 // or MAX SKILL ATK
)

func main() {
    dmgAbs := PvPFunc(DEF)
    fmt.Println("Min Damage:", MIN_ATK-dmgAbs, "Max Damage:", MAX_ATK-dmgAbs)
}

func PvPFunc(val int) int {
    v := math.Sqrt(float64(val))
    pow := 85 * math.E / 100
    v = math.Pow(v, pow)
    return int(v)
}

func ParseFloat(d string) float64 {
    f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(d, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return 0
    }

    return f
}
```

Whenever I give Go Build in the Command Prompt it gives the error:

```
utils / math.go: 128: 1: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: This is not javascript. Correct the tag!

Comment: I've fixed the tag. A reminder that if you have more than 3k rep, you can edit the post to change the tags instead of making a comment about it.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenient

Comment: I had to correct two errors to get it to compile: 1) add `package main` to the top, 2) add `"strconv"` to the import list. The result was `Min Damage: 6922 Max Damage: 26922`.  This is with go1.15 on macos 10.12.6.